# how to deploy an application for android devices in QT?

Tags: android, qt, c++11

I have developed an application for desktop use using qt.how can i deploy the same application for android mobile devices.is it possible? .if it is possible then it is  going to make any differences because of the coding language i have chosen (coding is done using c++).

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/portingtoandroid.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course!

First of all read the official documentation, [Qt for Android](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html). It's easy to set up. According to the [official guide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html):

- You need to download the Qt SDK for Android (arm or x86)
- Set up the environment by adding the path of your [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=es-419) &
  [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html?hl=es)
- If you only use libraries from Qt Framework then you should not have many problems to compile the project.
- You have to cross compile the other libraries by using the [ndk-tools](http://zwyuan.github.io/2015/12/22/three-ways-to-use-android-ndk-cross-compiler/).

Check this example of the [Qt Wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Create_and_Run_Qt_Application_for_Android)